# Speech recognition listen to long

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webspeech-api, annyang

I need your help I have no idea how to fix my issue.
I have app writen in ionic and I use annyang to Speech Recognition to listen what user said and response for that. 
It's working pretty good on web - using ionic serve, but when I run it on android device voice recognition take a long of time from 30s to couple of minutes - I just say one word for example "shop".

It's any way to decrease this time? Or can i set any of timeout?

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Edit: code look like

```
        //response is array of strings (three words)
        _.forEach(response, function (item) {
            annyang.addCommands(item,function(itme){
                 //check Something
            });            
        }

        annyang.start();
```

Edit2: here is this same, for resoult I have to wait 2min

```
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  console.log(event)
}
recognition.start();
```

Comment: Add code to your Q